# Walk me through the Linux log files (please)

Tags: linux, logging

I just tried loading a 2MB file in gedit and it silently died on me. I was wondering if anything might appear in a log file that might help me diagnose this: I checked `syslog` and found out it segfaulted. While doing this I realised that I don't really know anything about how logging is organised on *nix machines.

All I know at the mo is

1. Logs are typically stored in `/var/log/`... is there anywhere else that I should know about?
2. I'm familiar with application specific logs, such as apache's.
3. I understand that `dmesg` is the bootup log, and `syslog` is a general system log... is that right? **Edit:** Bobby says `dmesg` is also general purpose... what's the difference between the two?

So would someone mind taking me through the most useful logs? Are the two logs I mention in the final point the only *general* logs? And what are the funky numbers at the start of lines in `dmesg`? Seconds since startup?

Please include anything in your answers that you think would improve my understanding here and help me track down anomalies!

TIA

Andy

Comment: `dmesg` or `/var/log/messages` is a general message log, not just for the boot. Also, starting an application from terminal can help debugging a problem.

Comment: yeah I've noticed that if I start things through the command line I often get application-vomit coming back. If I start the same program through a graphical launcher is that text lost? Is it considered good practice for a graphical app to output messages to `stdout`?

Comment: If you start a program graphically, then stdout and stderr will be connected to nowhere (or /dev/null, for that matter), which means that all messages will be lost. If you need it, then either start from command line, or redirect the output to a file by setting the command in the .desktop file to something like this: "some_command &> some_logfile".

Comment: The real question is whether or not I need it! Do most programs leave more useful output in the logs? Do advanced Linux folk typically use the `stdout` to help diagnose problems with software (not their own)? (Basically I'm familiar with how to grab the `stdout`, but not with how useful the output may actually be...)

Comment: I only start applications from the terminal if I have problems with it (retrieving some debug information and error messages which might have been swallowed by the GUI). And yes, it is good practice and it is the standard behavior of all applications under Linux.

Comment: @Andy , would you consider changing the accepted answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a starter at LinuxHomeNetworking: [Quick HOWTO:Ch05:Troubleshooting Linux with syslog](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch05_:_Troubleshooting_Linux_with_syslog).

You might also like [Ubuntu Tips: How To View System Log Files in GUI](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/11/ubuntu-tips-how-to-view-system-log-files-in-gui/).

The [Ubuntu LinuxLogFiles](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles) page is also a good reference
<sup>(posted in a comment by `Pulse` to another answer here).</sup>

Answer (score 12):

Many thanks to Pulse for recommending https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles. I've cut some bits out, and left out how to use `syslogd` and other essential commands, to leave this little guide for future reference. *This is from an Ubuntu site and I don't know how much holds for other distros.*

> ## System Logs
>
> System logs deal primarily with the functioning of the Ubuntu system, not necessarily with additional applications added by users. Examples include authorization mechanisms, system daemons, system messages, and the all-encompassing system log itself, syslog.
>
> ### Authorization Log: `/var/log/auth.log`
>
> The Authorization Log tracks usage of authorization systems, the mechanisms for authorizing users which prompt for user passwords, such as the Pluggable Authentication Module (PAM) system, the `sudo` command, remote logins to `sshd` and so on.
>
> ### Daemon Log: `/var/log/daemon.log`
>
> The daemon log contains information about running system and application daemons such as the Gnome Display Manager daemon `gdm`, the Bluetooth HCI daemon `hcid`, or the MySQL database daemon `mysqld`.
>
> ### Debug Log: `/var/log/debug`
>
> The debug log provides detailed debug messages from the Ubuntu system and applications which log to `syslogd` at the DEBUG level.
>
> ### Kernel Log: `/var/log/kern.log`
>
> The kernel log provides a detailed log of messages from the Ubuntu Linux kernel. These messages may prove useful for trouble-shooting a new or custom-built kernel, for example.
>
> ### Kernel Ring Buffer: `dmesg`
>
> The kernel ring buffer is not really a log file per se, but rather an area in the running kernel you can query for kernel bootup messages via the `dmesg` utility. To see the messages, use this:
>
> `dmesg | less`
>
> By default, the system initialization script `/etc/init.d/bootmisc.sh` sends all bootup messages to the file `/var/log/dmesg` as well.
>
> ### Messages Log: `/var/log/messages`
>
> The messages log contains informational messages from applications, and system facilities. This log is useful for examining message output from applications, and system facilities which log to the `syslog` / `sysklog` daemon at the INFO level.
>
> ### System Log: `/var/log/syslog`
>
> The system log typically contains the greatest deal of information by default about your Ubuntu system. It may contain information other logs do not. Consult the System Log when you can't locate the desired log information in another log.
>
> ## Application Logs
>
> Many applications also create logs in `/var/log`. If you list the contents of your `/var/log` subdirectory, you will see familiar names, such as `/var/log/apache2` representing the logs for the Apache 2 web server, or `/var/log/samba`, which contains the logs for the Samba server.
>
> ### Apache HTTP Server Logs: `/var/log/apache2`
>
> The default installation for Apache2 on Ubuntu creates a log subdirectory. Within this subdirectory are two log files with two distinct purposes:
>
> - `/var/log/apache2/access.log` - records of every page served and every file loaded by the web server.
> - `/var/log/apache2/error.log` - records of all error conditions reported by the HTTP server
>
> ### CUPS Print System Logs: `/var/log/cups/error_log`
>
> The Common Unix Printing System (CUPS) uses the default log file `/var/log/cups/error_log` to store informational and error messages.
>
> ### Rootkit Hunter Log: `/var/log/rkhunter.log`
>
> The Rootkit Hunter utility (`rkhunter`) checks your Ubuntu system for backdoors, sniffers and rootkits, which are all signs of compromise of your system.
>
> ### Samba SMB Server Logs: `/var/log/samba`
>
> The Server Message Block Protocol (SMB) server, Samba is popularly used for sharing files between your Ubuntu computer and other computers which support the SMB protocol. Samba keeps three distinct types of logs in the subdirectory:
>
> - `log.nmbd` - messages related to Samba's NETBIOS over IP functionality (the network stuff)
> - `log.smbd` - messages related to Samba's SMB/CIFS functionality (the file and print sharing stuff)
> - `log.[IP_ADDRESS]` - messages related to requests for services from the IP address contained in the log file name.
>
> ### X11 Server Log: `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`
>
> The default X11 Windowing Server in use with Ubuntu is the Xorg X11 server. This log is helpful for diagnosing issues with your X11 environment.
>
> ## Non-Human-Readable Logs
>
> Some log files found in the `/var/log` subdirectory are designed to be readable by applications, not necessarily by humans. Some examples follow.
>
> ### Login Failures Log: `faillog`
>
> The login failures log located at `/var/log/faillog` is actually designed to be parsed and displayed by the `faillog` command.
>
> ### Last Logins Log: `lastlog`
>
> The last logins log at `/var/log/lastlog` should not typically be parsed and examined by humans, but rather should be used in conjunction with the `lastlog` command.
>
> ### Login Records Log: `who`
>
> The file `/var/log/wtmp` contains login records, but unlike `/var/log/lastlog` above, `/var/log/wtmp` is not used to show a list of recent logins, but is instead used by other utilities such as the `who` command to present a listed of currently logged in users.

Answer (score 1):

[syslog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog) (or rather, `syslog.d`) is a logging system, which is responsible for writing most logs in `/var/log`. There are other similar projects, like [syslog-ng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog-ng)

`system.log` is just a specifically named file that syslog happens to write to

Comment: Thanks for the response: I was more interested in an overall picture of Linux logging. My example with syslog was just a preamble to explain how I got to this general question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say where you are based, but [Linux Format](http://linuxformat.co.uk) had an article in Issue 132 covering log files. You'll either need to find someone with a copy or buy a back issue to get hold of it though.

Comment: I'm based in the UK, but still would hope I can get the info without spending money(:

Comment: I'm still learning linux and I found this to be a useful page of information https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles

Comment: That's just what I was after!